# Function "date" with arguments in Bash -- "'date --help' for more information. "

Tags: linux, bash

I'm defining a variable:

```
my_dt=$(date + "%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
```

Bash is saying

```
date: extra operand ‘%a, %d %b %Y %T %z’                                                                                                                      
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

And "echo $my_dt" prints nothing

Answer (score 1):

There is a space between the + operator and the "
It should be fixed :

```
my_dt=$(date +"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")
```